# What is a good word for "introduction" as a section heading in a written piece?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

A Google search gives a few possibilities, and I'm not sure how these differ or which would be appropriate:

- Einführung
- Einleitung
- Bekanntschaft
- Vorstellung

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Einleitung* would be the most common, I think. *Einführung* (which can also mean *insertion*, depending on context) is not wrong, but usually refers to something broader, like an introductory course or similar. Your last two examples (i.e. *Bekanntschaft* and *Vorstellung*) refer to persons being introduced or getting to know one another.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the type of document you want to write, it is difficult to decide. For technical papers frequently something like *Motivation* (same meaning as in English) appears at the beginning, to describe starting point and to problems to be addressed in the paper.

Comment: It is not difficult to decide that options 3 and 4 from the question are entirely unsuitable.